# How can I access variables (inside a coroutine) from mainActivity?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, scope, kotlin-coroutines

thank you in advance for your time!

I am practicing API & network calls, so I build a small up to get a list of players from a public API and show it in a recyclerView @MainActivity. Simple.

The problem is that, apart from sending the list to the recyclerView Adapter from the coroutine, I want to be able to store the list somewhere so I can access it from outside the coroutine.

This way I can work with the list of players without the network call

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home)

        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {

            // Here we store the data received in a generic type "response"
            val response = LaRojaService
                .getLaRojaDataService()
                .getLaRojaPlayers()

            // Return to UI thread to process the data and inflate the recyclerView with it
            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                if (response.isSuccessful) {
                    val temp = response.body()
                    val tempList = mutableListOf<Player>()

                    var index = 0
                    temp?.forEach {
                        val active = temp[index].active
                        val bio = temp[index].bio
                        val gamesPlayed = temp[index].gamesPlayed
                        val goalsScored = temp[index].goalsScored
                        val name = temp[index].name
                        val number = temp[index].number
                        val playerPictureUrl = temp[index].playerPictureUrl
                        val position = temp[index].position
                        val profilePictureUrl = temp[index].profilePictureUrl
                        val seasonsActive = temp[index].seasonsActive

                        tempList.add(Player(active, bio, gamesPlayed, goalsScored, name,
                            number, playerPictureUrl, position, profilePictureUrl, seasonsActive))

                        index += 1
                    }
                    recyclerView_home.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@HomeActvity)
                    recyclerView_home.adapter = HomePlayerAdapter(tempList)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**What this does:**

```
- Get a list of players from a public API using a coroutine
- Inflate the recyclerView with the list created on the MainThread
```

**What I need it to do:**

```
- Get a list of players from the API using the coroutine
- Save the list outside the coroutine (In this case, MainActivity)
- Work through the data inside the mainActivity
- Inflate the recyclerView (From Main activity)
```

Thank you again so much. I am still very confused in this topic. I don't even know if it's possible.

Comment: Why not just declare a property in `MainActivity`?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that, i'm still learning and i've spent a few hours on this, so it's driving me crazy :(
Could you put an example? Thank you!

Comment: Maybe take a look at the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/properties.html)? I would definitely recommend taking a beginners Kotlin tutorial before attempting an app. It'll make everything a lot easier and faster for you!

Comment: I would not recommend trying to learn coroutines before you understand properties, lambdas, and inline functions. The way you’re doing your coroutine breaks several conventions but it won’t help to explain them all now if you didn’t understand the bit about creating a property.

Comment: I understand how to create a property, but i can't assign it the values i got from the response.body

Comment: Can you show that code so we can see what’s preventing you from doing it?